# What is the correct phrasal verb for "integration by parts"?

Tags: synonyms, phrasal-verbs, mathematics

When speaking in conversation, or writing up a paper, and applying the said technique on a function, is it correct to say "partially integrate"?

e.g.

"We partially integrate X..."

versus

"We integrate X by parts..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say "We integrate *X* by parts."

If someone said "partial integration" I may be inclined to try to think of some sort of inverse of partial differentiation.

On the other hand, one does see "partial integration" for "integration by parts" sometimes; I am guessing this is literally translated from some other language.